# rsync to remote server with time difference by seconds

Tags: rsync

I use `rsync -vua` to sync my local files to remote server. However,

The problem is that the remote server's time is faster by just 1 second, which causes the problem that when I do `rsync -vua` again, I'll get a huge list of `some file is newer`, instead of a clean output of nothing need to be transferred.

Syncing my time on my *local machine* doesn't help.

The remote server is Debian 11.

Local machine is WSL Debian 11:

```
$ apt-cache policy rsync
rsync:
  Installed: 3.2.3-4+deb11u1
  Candidate: 3.2.3-4+deb11u1
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.3-4+deb11u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ rsync -V
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31
```

**UPDATE:**

I installed ntp to the remote server (thanks for the suggestion), but its time is faster by just sub seconds now (thus the problem reported is OP still remains), as my local machine is Windows. I know in theory remote and local would have exactly the same time, however, the reality is:

```
$ sudo ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.000
 1.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.000
 2.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.000
 3.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.000
-65-100-46-166.d .SOCK.           1 u  201 1024  377   83.923   -1.124   0.197
-time.skylineser 130.207.244.240  2 u  530 1024  377   27.402   -1.442   0.440
*50.205.244.112  50.205.244.28    2 u  617 1024  377   16.331   +0.940   0.344
-168.61.215.74   25.66.230.4      3 u  382 1024  377   23.048   -0.565   0.280
+23.157.160.168  129.6.15.28      2 u  363 1024  377    7.697   +0.106   0.876
+45.83.234.123 ( 10.1.105.4       2 u  606 1024  377   85.007   +0.903   0.242
```

Seems that even some time server cannot agree with each other.

So Windows and Debian time servers have sub-second differences seems quit possible.

Answer (score 0):

You've already hit on the source of the problem - time synchronization. NTP (or another time sync process) must be enabled on both servers - remote and local.

Comment: OK, I installed ntp to the remote server (thanks for the suggestion), but its time is faster by just sub seconds now (thus the problem reported is OP still remains), as my local machine is Windows. I know in theory remote and local would have exactly the same time, however, somehow my situation is not.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said why you're using the `-u` option, which skips files that have a newer timestamp at the destination.  If this is important, then it might not be easy to avoid these error messages.

One thing you can try is to make rsync choose the files to transfer based on the contents of their checksums with the `-c` option.  Add the `-c` option after your usual `-va` options:

```
    rsync -va -c
or
    rsync -vac
```

(doesn't make sense to keep `-u` when `-c` defeats it)

Depending on the number of files you're transferring and the cpu power available at each end, calculating the file checksums can slow the transfer session down somewhat.  But hey, no more timestamp complaints!

Comment: OK I gave `rsync -vac` a try, but I'm still getting `some file is newer` warnings. You can `touch` a remote file and try it yourself.